# Beamer Warsaw customization

Tags: beamer, fonts, backgrounds

Hello I am trying to customize a beamer, with my colors for the title, font, colors for the header and background color. But I don't understand much about the subject, I have looked for similar questions but I haven't found much, I put my little advance:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, usenames, dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\usetheme{Warsaw}
%\usecolortheme{wolverine}
%\usecolortheme{default}
\definecolor{Mcolor}{RGB}{0, 72, 179}
%\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
\usecolortheme[named=Mcolor]{structure}


\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
    colback=bg, 
    colframe=blue!75!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=blue!75!black, 
    colbacktitle=bg,
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-1.2mm, xshift=2mm},
  title=#2,
  #1}


\title[Title] 
{Title}

\author[Author] 
{Auhor\inst{1}}
\institute[VFU] 
{
  \inst{1}%
  Departament
}

\logo{\includegraphics[height=1.3cm]{Logo.png}}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title}
    \begin{mybox}{Example}
        Hello $x^4+1=0$
    \end{mybox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If someone has examples using any type of color it would help me a lot, I am not looking for someone to solve my problem (I would be very grateful if that were the case). If anyone has a document that can help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Just to fix ideas and standardize my question I would like to see:
Font: comic sans, color: blue
Title type: times new roman, color: red
Background: some kind of watermark or a smooth image
Header and footer color: green (I think this part if I managed it in the code)

I know I'm asking a lot but any help is welcome. Thanks

Comment: Please don't ask for Comic Sans :)